# What does the first variable do in nparange(x, y, z)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

So I am learning to makes graphs with matplotlib and I don't really know numpy very well yet. When setting up my yticks I am using np.arange(0, 80000, 10000) and I can't figure out what the first variable is for, can anyone help me with this?

I've tried changing the variable to larger numbers and the only thing I've noticed is a longer load time and the CPU getting taxed harder.

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 6
catPopulation = (20000, 35000, 30000, 35000, 27000, 33000)
dogPopulation = (25000, 32000, 34000, 20000, 25000, 33000)
ind = np.arange(N)  
width = 0.11       

p1 = plt.bar(ind, catPopulation, width)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, dogPopulation, width,
             bottom=catPopulation)

plt.ylabel('Population Per City')
plt.title('Comparing Cat and Dog Populations For Different Cities')
plt.xticks(ind, ('Houston', 'Detroid', 'Chicago', 'Los Angelos', 'New York', 'Sacramento'))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 80000, 10000))
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Cats', 'Dogs'))
plt.show()
```

Comment: np.arange itself is fairly simple; the first number (if you give it three arguments) represents the number to start the range at. I think your core question might actually be about the interaction between np.arange, plt.bar, and plt.yticks

Comment: The question is not about matplotlib but numpy/ tag removed. Just read [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)

Answer (score 3):

According to [numpy's documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), the signature for arange is:

```
numpy.arange([start, ]stop, [step, ]dtype=None)
```

so, your three numbers are:
start: 0
stop: 80000
step: 10000

So, from 0 to 80,000, stepping every 10,000. This array [is the first argument for yticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html)

```
yticks(ticks, [labels], **kwargs)  # Set locations and labels
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out, it's where the counting starts at.